# jquery load() gives 405 error when passing parameters

Tags: jquery, load

I'm loading an external file and populating a DIV using jQuery load().

If I don't pass any parameters, it works:

```
$("#adminContent").load("../data/homepage.html",function(){
```

but if I try to pass a paramenter, I get the error
*POST http://example.com/data/homepage.html 405 (Method Not Allowed)*

```
var belongsTo="1";
$("#adminContent").load("../data/homepage.html",{"belongsTo":belongsTo},function(){
```

why?

Comment: This is a server-side issue. The server does not like you trying to make a POST request to that page, apparently. I'm guessing by default, that `$.fn.load()` uses GET if no data is passed, so that's why that works.

Comment: Yep. From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method): "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." One option would be to pass the parameters as a string, not an object.